# Ruby gsub then freeze get different object_id

Tags: ruby, gsub, freeze

I've made an experiment about ruby's freeze:

```
# example1
a = 'a'.freeze

puts "--Identical object_id--"
puts a.object_id
puts 'a'.freeze.object_id


# example 2
b = 'a'.gsub('a', 'b').freeze
another_b = 'a'.gsub('a', 'b').freeze

puts "--Got three different object_id--"
puts 'b'.freeze.object_id
puts b.object_id
puts another_b.object_id
b.frozen? #=> true
```

b and another_b are frozen string 'b', why they have different object_id?

Comment: Because they are different instances of String class

Comment: Only frozen string **literals** result in the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby (YARV) recognizes frozen string literals and creates an optimized instruction sequence:

```
$ ruby --dump=insns -e '"a".freeze'
== disasm: #<ISeq:<main>@-e:1 (1,0)-(1,3)>==============================
0000 opt_str_freeze   "a"                                             (   1)[Li]
0002 leave
```

as opposed to a non-frozen string:

```
$ ruby --dump=insns -e '"a"'
== disasm: #<ISeq:<main>@-e:1 (1,0)-(1,3)>==============================
0000 putstring        "a"                                             (   1)[Li]
0002 leave
```

Strings that have been optimized this way will refer to the very same object, i.e. they have the same `object_id`. But it only works for string *literals*, i.e. `"...".freeze`. Invoking `freeze` via `send(:freeze)` or calling `freeze` on a a string with interpolation or a non-literal like a variable or the result of a method call results in an ordinary method call:

```
$ ruby --dump=insns -e '"a".to_s.freeze'
== disasm: #<ISeq:<main>@-e:1 (1,0)-(1,15)>=============================
0000 putstring        "a"                                             (   1)[Li]
0002 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:to_s, argc:0, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0005 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:freeze, argc:0, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0008 leave
```

A string frozen this way will be a distinct object with a different `object_id`.

Note that all of this is implementation specific. You should not rely on these optimizations.